# Prevent inline SVG pixel snapping in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have an svg that I'm using to show a wavy edge on a div. The svg needs to display as the same with as the div but due to some sub pixel snapping/rounding the alignment varies as you resize. Firefox seems to work fine. See demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/meojwnLv/

When using the svg as a background image with `background-size:100% auto;` it scales correctly but I want to be able to change the color so need it to be inline.

How can I prevent this from happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Chrome is snapping the height *and width* of the SVG object to integer values. Since the SVG's width is much larger than its height, every 1px change in the height of the SVG is causing the width to change by about 10px.

```
viewBox="20 20 900 66"
```

There's an easy workaround for this — just make the SVG taller:

```
viewBox="20 20 900 500"
```

[Here's an updated JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/meojwnLv/1/)

Comment: thanks, doesn't completely solve it but it's a good workaround and I understand what's happening better now